# Get HTML values from web response

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, httpwebresponse

I am trying to parse an HTML response for a couple of values and then insert them into SQL.  I am able to get both values but, because the code is wrapped in a foreach statement, I get them twice.

Here is my HTML response

```
<div align="CENTER" class='dataTitle'>Host State Breakdowns:</div>
<p align='center'>
<a href='trends.cgi?host=hostname&includesoftstates=no&assumeinitialstates=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&backtrack=4'><img src='trends.cgi?createimage&host=hostname&includesoftstates=no&initialassumedhoststate=0&backtrack=4' border="1" alt='Host State Trends' title='Host State Trends' width='500' height='20'></a><br>
</p>
<div align="CENTER">
<table border="0" class='data'>
<tr><th class='data'>State</th><th class='data'>Type / Reason</th><th class='data'>Time</th><th class='data'>% Total Time</th><th class='data'>% Known Time</th></tr>
<tr class='dataEven'><td class='hostUP' rowspan="3">UP</td><td class='dataEven'>Unscheduled</td><td class='dataEven'>0d 10h 5m 19s</td><td class='dataEven'>100.000%</td><td class='dataEven'>100.000%</td></tr>
<tr class='dataEven'><td class='dataEven'>Scheduled</td><td class='dataEven'>0d 0h 0m 0s</td><td class='dataEven'>0.000%</td><td class='dataEven'>0.000%</td></tr>
<tr class='hostUNREACHABLE'><td class='hostUNREACHABLE'>Total</td><td class='hostUNREACHABLE'>0d 0h 0m 0s</td><td class='hostUNREACHABLE'>0.000%</td><td class='hostUNREACHABLE'>0.000%</td></tr>
<tr class='dataOdd'><td class='dataOdd' rowspan="3">Undetermined</td><td class='dataOdd'>Nagios Not Running</td><td class='dataOdd'>0d 0h 0m 0s</td><td class='dataOdd'>0.000%</td><td class='dataOdd'></td></tr>
<tr class='dataOdd'><td class='dataOdd'>Insufficient Data</td><td class='dataOdd'>0d 0h 0m 0s</td><td class='dataOdd'>0.000%</td><td class='dataOdd'></td></tr>
<tr class='dataOdd'><td class='dataOdd'>Total</td><td class='dataOdd'>0d 0h 0m 0s</td><td class='dataOdd'>0.000%</td><td class='dataOdd'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
<tr class='dataEven'><td class='dataEven'>All</td><td class='dataEven'>Total</td><td class='dataEven'>0d 10h 5m 19s</td><td class='dataEven'>100.000%</td><td class='dataEven'>100.000%</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br><br>
<div align="CENTER" class='dataTitle'>State Breakdowns For Host Services:</div>
<div align="CENTER">
<table border="0" class='data'>
<tr><th class='data'>Service</th><th class='data'>% Time OK</th><th class='data'>% Time Warning</th><th class='data'>% Time Unknown</th><th class='data'>% Time Critical</th><th class='data'>% Time Undetermined</th></tr>
<tr class='dataOdd'><td class='dataOdd'><a href='avail.cgi?host=hostname&service=servicename&t1=1478498400&t2=1478534719&backtrack=4&assumestateretention=yes&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&show_log_entries&showscheduleddowntime=yes&rpttimeperiod=24x7'>servicename</a></td><td class='serviceOK'>100.000% (100.000%)</td><td class='serviceWARNING'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='serviceUNKNOWN'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='serviceCRITICAL'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='dataOdd'>0.000%</td></tr>
<tr class='dataEven'><td class='dataEven'><a href='avail.cgi?host=hostname&service=servicename2&t1=1478498400&t2=1478534719&backtrack=4&assumestateretention=yes&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&show_log_entries&showscheduleddowntime=yes&rpttimeperiod=24x7'>servicename2</a></td><td class='serviceOK'>100.000% (100.000%)</td><td class='serviceWARNING'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='serviceUNKNOWN'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='serviceCRITICAL'>0.000% (0.000%)</td><td class='dataEven'>0.000%</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(stream);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class]"))
{

    foreach (HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//td[@class = 'serviceOK']"))
    {
        var value = node2.InnerText;
    }

    foreach (HtmlNode node3 in node.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, 'avail.cgi')]"))
    {
        var name = node3.InnerText;
    }

}
```

name shows the servicename and value shows the class serviceOK but it repeats itself again because of the first foreach.

My results look like this:

```
100.000% (100.000%)
100.000% (100.000%)
servicename
servicename2
100.000% (100.000%)
100.000% (100.000%)
servicename
servicename2
```

Is there a way to, first, match the values up, and two, only have them show once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first foreach traverses the entire document as do both of your other foreach statements inside of the first.
Because there are 2 table elements matching your XPath expression

```
"//table[@class]"
```

you are getting your answer twice. If you had more table elements matching your XPath expression, say 7 for example, you would get the result 7 times.
What you want is to find all table divisions (td) with class "serviceOK" that are within a table row (tr) within a table.
Once you have this HtmlNode you can just go to the previous sibling which will contain the service name.

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(stream);

foreach (HtmlNode serviceOkNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class]/tr/td[@class = 'serviceOK']"))
{
    HtmlNode serviceNameNode = serviceOkNode.PreviousSibling;
    var value = serviceOkNode.InnerText;
    var name = serviceNameNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much.  I knew the first foreach was throwing me off but I couldn't figure out what I needed to use for the SelectNodes.  Thank you again